# WCF Transaction Flow not getting committed on success

Tags: .net, sql-server, wcf, transactions

I have been trying to implement the transaction flow in WCF. When I am executing My Client code I could see that the transaction is propagating to the Service from client as I see the record is locked in db(I used with(nolock) in SQL server to see if the transaction is happening). However my client code completes successfully, but the transaction is rolled back, Do I miss something here,

following are the code snippets,

Service class

```
[ServiceBehavior( TransactionIsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted,  TransactionTimeout = "00:00:30")]
public class TransactionTest : ITransactionTest
{
[OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true, TransactionAutoComplete = false)]
public void DoWork(string aliasName)
{    
    string constr = "Data Source=MyDBServer;User ID=DBUser;password=123;Initial Catalog=MyTestDB;";
    using (SqlConnection objcon = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        string qry = @"UPDATE Customer SET Alias = '" + aliasName + "' WHERE CustomerID = 10";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, objcon);
        objcon.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

}

```
 Service Contract:

 [ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required)]
 public interface ITransactionTest
 {
    [OperationContract, TransactionFlow(TransactionFlowOption.Allowed)]    
void DoWork(string aliasName);
 }
```

following is my Web.config

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsHttpBinding_ITransactionTest" transactionFlow="true"/>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

I have added a service reference in my client application (which is a console application)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        //updateCustomeAlias();
        try
        {
            using (TransactionScope TranScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
            {
                var proxy = new TransactionTestClient("WSHttpBinding_ITransactionTest");
                proxy.DoWork("XYZ");
                TranScope.Complete();
            }
        }
        catch 
        { 
            //Exception handling.
        }
    }
```

Client application config

```
 <system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WSHttpBinding_ITransactionTest" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
      openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
      bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text"
      textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
        enabled="false" />
      <security mode="Message">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
          algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:91/TransactionTest.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_ITransactionTest" contract="TransactionTestService.ITransactionTest"          
    name="WSHttpBinding_ITransactionTest">        
  </endpoint>
</client>
 </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

On the service side you have `[OperationBehavior(TransactionAutoComplete = false)]` which means that the service must explicitly vote to commit or a roll back will happen. You have two options. On the service side either:

1. Change the behavior to `TransactionAutoComplete = true` which will automatically vote to commit the transaction unless there is an exception.
2. In the service method `TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required)` will get the ambient transaction scope which you can call `Complete()` on.

Comment: If I specify TransactionAutoComplete = False then the client transaction is not propagated to the Service.

Comment: I don't understand. You say "the transaction is propagating to the Service from client" and your code as posted sets TransactionAutoComplete = False... nothing has changed and its not propagated?